# how many rupee or dollar charge to client to make theme

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I have a client they saying, make theme for me, i will sell it in the online market, i agreed to make wordpress theme with plugin integration but i dont know how many amount to charge for theme, anyone knowhow many rupees or dollar can i charge to them.

Comment: as much as you think they will be willing to pay, but no less then what you could have earned by doing some other work in the time that it will take you.

Comment: they dont have any idea, they had told me to say amount

Comment: and also i dont have any idea

Comment: Sorry, but these type of questions are really off topic here. It is too broad, based on personal experience, opinion etc etc

Comment: @MarkKaplun I think that is just the perfect comment to a question like this. Short and sweet :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its depends on the time taken to complete the project plus complexity. You can charge on hourly basis like 20 USD per hour. Some times project has more value than you charge, like you said that client wants to sell the theme on marketplace, so in that case you should charge more because he will need your support until the product on marketplace.

Don't be greedy but don't afraid to charge more.